# Multiple definition errors when compiling gcc 4 with gcc 11

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I am following along an operating systems class from Spring 2023 and trying to setup an environment using their [instructions](https://student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecs350/common/Install161NonCS.html) so that I can do the class assignments. Part of those instructions are building a modified gcc 4.1.2.

I'm on RHEL using gcc 11.3.1, and I'm getting multiple definition error when building gcc regarding exact_log2 and floor_log2 functions in `toplev.h` and `toplev.c`. Here's some example output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: attribs.o: in function `floor_log2':
/home/ec2-user/gcc-4.1.2+os161-2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/../.././gcc/toplev.h:177: multiple definition of `floor_log2'; c-lang.o:/home/ec2-user/gcc-4.1.2+os161-2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/../.././gcc/toplev.h:177: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: attribs.o: in function `exact_log2':
/home/ec2-user/gcc-4.1.2+os161-2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/../.././gcc/toplev.h:183: multiple definition of `exact_log2'; c-lang.o:/home/ec2-user/gcc-4.1.2+os161-2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/../.././gcc/toplev.h:183: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: c-errors.o: in function `floor_log2':
/home/ec2-user/gcc-4.1.2+os161-2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/../.././gcc/toplev.h:177: multiple definition of `floor_log2'; c-lang.o:/home/ec2-user/gcc-4.1.2+os161-2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/../.././gcc/toplev.h:177: first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: c-errors.o: in function `exact_log2':
/home/ec2-user/gcc-4.1.2+os161-2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/../.././gcc/toplev.h:183: multiple definition of `exact_log2'; c-lang.o:/home/ec2-user/gcc-4.1.2+os161-2.0/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/../.././gcc/toplev.h:183: first defined here
```

It seems like this has something to do with [gcc now using -fno-common flag by default](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html), but I tried adding -fcommon to my Makefile CFLAGS without success.

In the toplev.h code there is an #ifdef block with inline functions of both exact_log2 and floor_log2:

```
/* Inline versions of the above for speed.  */
#if GCC_VERSION >= 3004

extern inline int
exact_log2 (unsigned HOST_WIDE_INT x)
{
  return x == (x & -x) && x ? (int) CTZ_HWI (x) : -1;
}

#endif /* GCC_VERSION >= 3004 */
```

Comment: Have you got any inline code in toplev.h

Comment: @cup Yeah, there is an inline of each function in an #ifdef block. I added info to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple definitions are caused by the inline code.  A few solutions:

1. Make the definition static instead of extern.  This means that there will be a copy in every file but they can't see each other so the linker doesn't care
2. Move the code body into a .cpp file and forget about inlining.
3. If you really, really want it inlined, do it as a macro.  Since it is just a single line, it doesn't make very much difference in debugging.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid modifying the code since it does not say to do so in the instructions. I was thinking it could  be fixed with some build options, maybe?